# Printer spooler spoolsv.exe crashes

Tags: windows, printing

We have a problem with a Windows 7 print spooler. There is a Windows 2011 Small Business Server running as print server and 2 computers in the network their print spooler keeps crashing at random. The log files says it is ntdll.dll that has a fault.

```
Naam van toepassing met fout: spoolsv.exe, versie: 6.1.7601.17514, tijdstempel: 0x4ce7b4e7
Naam van module met fout: ntdll.dll, versie: 6.1.7601.17725, tijdstempel: 0x4ec4aa8e
Uitzonderingscode: 0xc0000374
Foutoffset: 0x00000000000c40f2
Id van proces met fout: 0x55c
Starttijd van toepassing met fout: 0x01cd9db324904eb1
Pad naar toepassing met fout: C:\Windows\System32\spoolsv.exe
Pad naar module met fout: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Rapport-id: 8789af0b-09a6-11e2-9d78-001c25237c45
```

The print spooler on the server keeps running and works fine. We can also print from other computers. But on two computers the print spooler crashes. Sometimes it crashes after a user is logged in, but it also happened multiple times after a print job.
After each crash we get the same ntdll.dll error.

Hopefully someone can help me with this problem. If you need more information, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: May it be the case? http://www.spoolsvexe.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is happening to more than one PC it's a pretty sure bet that you have a driver issue. Try to upgrade the driver and if you have a choice of drivers don't use the "Microsoft" one. Although those drivers are supplied by the device manufacturers, they are generally the last to get upgraded, so are also the most likely to contain bugs.

Comment: Thanks that worked. We reinstalled all the drivers with the latest driver version. We also found out that a scanner driver was installed at the sime time when the problems started. We also removed that driver.